# Entitiy Framework increment not working? giving Error

Tags: c#, sql, database, algorithm, entity-framework

hello in my code increment not working thus it gives me error,
i don't know what is wrong with this.
my column is primary as auto increment is ON

```
foreach (var item in Items)
{
    using (var db = new TempDGREntities())
    {
               //code here auto incrementing
        using (var context = new TempDGREntities())
        {

            try
            {
                foreach (var car in list)
                {
                    //code here NOT auto incrementing
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u check after savechanges in db? `gives me an error` wt is the error.

Comment: What error do you get? How did you configure your Primary-Key-Properties?

Comment: for car1 it inserts to DB, but for car2 ID is not changing and it gives ERROR.

Comment: @maxamus.maxamus wt is the column name?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: maybe i should do sth in SQL

Comment: Can you show your `Items` and `list` model?